# He said he has read that book VS He said he had read that book

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, reported-speech

> He said he has read that book.

> He said he had read that book.

Both of these sentences are grammatically correct.

It seems there is a nuance in meaning between them. So, what is the nuance?

Comment: Reported speech about a situation that is still true can be in either the past or the present tense; in this case it makes no difference. If what the person said in the past may no longer be true, there is a potential difference in meaning. Compare [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/244307/found-out-that-she-had-a-boyfriend-vs-found-out-that-she-has-a-boyfriend?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

I've never come across the **He said he has read the book** kind of sentence. If you want to use Indirect Speech, I suggest you use the second sentence. **The past tense** always matches their counterparts (*past continuous, past perfect, past perfect continuous, would*), so does **the present tense** (*present continuous, present perfect, present perfect continuous, will*). This first clause of the first sentence *He said* is the simple past tense and the second clause, *he has read*, is the present perfect tense; therefore, the sentence is uncoordinated. However, the second sentence, *He said* (which is the simple past tense) and *he had read that* (the past perfect tense), matches each other.

I'm pretty sure most native speakers would let this slide if you ever said the former.

Comment: It is common to see the simple past is followed by the present perfect in reported speech. Are you really sure most native speakers would consider my first example unacceptable?

Comment: I'm saying that they would understand what you say because both the meanings of the sentences are the same, despite the tense. And maybe it's common as you said but I  recently saw different cases like **Copernicus stated that the earth orbits the sun**, meaning that it is a general fact that the earth orbits the sun even though the statement was made a long time ago. Or **He has said he likes apples**.